# How to change unit of temperature shown in GNOME Calendar?

Tags: unity, gnome-calendar, ubuntu-unity

I installed GNOME Calendar in Ubuntu Unity 22.10, and it shows the predicted temperature on each day in the calendar.

However, it is showing the temperature in Fahrenheit, and I want to view the temperature in Celsius. How do I achieve this?

Comment: This is a bit tricky to figure out in non-GNOME flavors, where the weather app is not installed by default, but other apps like calendar can display the temperature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested by @muru, it can be changed with gsettings.
In Ubuntu 22.04,

```
gsettings set org.gnome.GWeather temperature-unit centigrade
```

For later Ubuntu versions,

```
gsettings set org.gnome.GWeather4 temperature-unit centigrade
```

---

### Alternative solution

Ubuntu Unity does not have either GNOME Calendar or GNOME Weather installed by default. I manually installed GNOME Calendar. While it did show the temperature, there was no way to configure the units.

The solution is to install GNOME Weather, and change the units in its configuration. GNOME Calendar will then automatically pick it up.

```
sudo apt install gnome-weather
```

[image]

Comment: This would be gsettings configuration as well, can you just change it there?

Comment: @muru I am not familiar with gsettings configurations (mostly because I have not used GNOME since its version 3 was released). Feel free to edit the answer/add a new answer.

Comment: I don't have an instance around to test, but can you try `gsettings set org.gnome.GWeather4 temperature-unit centigrade`?

Comment: @muru That works!!